# How to make a windows form fit for all screens

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application which have 10 forms nearly. i want to make the application to fit for all types of screens from 13 inches to 18 inches. Any suggestions will help me a lot

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Are you stuck on anything special?

Comment: Make a function that changes their size depending on the window size and call that function in the resize event

Comment: No need for a method, you can dock and anchor controls so their size/position changes as the size of the window does. Your question is too broad however since whether or not that is a viable solution depends on your application. Otherwise you just pick a resolution for your app and make all your windows that size (640 * 480 is a good one right?)

Comment: Well, this is simple, just run your window maximized :)  Creating a *layout* of your controls that's well proportioned for every possible screen size is however a designer's job.  Take some cues from Visual Studio itself, observe how it behaves when you resize its main window.  It took more than one programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Make your dialogs resizable.
Make use of the containers that are available in windows forms.
These will make sure that if in fact the dialog is resized, the elements that are contained in the form are also resized proportionally taking the new size of the form into account.
You want to checkout the TableLayoutPanel

Other things to consider is for all the elements on your form how to anchor them, how to place them and dock them in a parent control, .... These properties  are named as such Anchor and Dock and can be found in the properties.

At dialog level you can also control the position of the dialog on the screen by setting a value to the StartPosition and the WindowsState.

If you want even more control than this you can make use of the Screen object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: +1 for mentioning TableLayoutPanel. I find it amazingly helpful and yet it is so rarely used by many IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

/*Form Properties -> Doc = fill*/